# Image segregation by k-mean python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, machine-learning, k-means

I'm new to machine learning and i was learning k-mean for image segregation but i'm unable to understand code for it :

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
image = imread(os.path.join("images","unsupervised_learning","ladybug.png"))
image.shape
X = image.reshape(-1, 3)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=8, random_state=42).fit(X)
segmented_img = kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_]
segmented_img = segmented_img.reshape(image.shape)
segmented_imgs = []
n_colors = (10, 8, 6, 4, 2)
for n_clusters in n_colors:
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=42).fit(X)
    segmented_img = kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_]
    segmented_imgs.append(segmented_img.reshape(image.shape))
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.1)
plt.subplot(231)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title("Original image")
plt.axis('off')
for idx, n_clusters in enumerate(n_colors):
   plt.subplot(232 + idx)
   plt.imshow(segmented_imgs[idx])
   plt.title("{} colors".format(n_clusters))
   plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

image used :
[image]
the output figure
[image]

specially,what this code mean

```
segmented_img = kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_]
```

Comment: Do you know how k-means works?

Comment: This is not "segregation", it is called "color quantization". Knowing the right term might help you finding relevant sources. For example, there are quite a few questions on here about color quantization algorithms, and Wikipedia has a reasonable article about it as well.

Comment: yes i know how k-mean works

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you start off by reading up on unsupervised learning, specially clustering using K-means and it's applications/concepts in general, not just for images.

I'll comment each line of this code to explain what is happening.

```
from matplotlib.image import imread #import module
image = imread(os.path.join("images","unsupervised_learning","ladybug.png")) #Read Image
image.shape #Get shape of image, which is height, width and channel(colours)
X = image.reshape(-1, 3) #Reshaping to get color channel first
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=8, random_state=42).fit(X) #Applying and fitting K-means clustering
segmented_img = kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_] #centres of the 8 clusters made
segmented_img = segmented_img.reshape(image.shape) #reshape them using the changed image shape
segmented_imgs = []
n_colors = (10, 8, 6, 4, 2) 
for n_clusters in n_colors:
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=42).fit(X) #Applyting kmeans for each colour, using 10,8,6.... as number of clusters
    segmented_img = kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_] #Repeating as mentioned above
    segmented_imgs.append(segmented_img.reshape(image.shape))
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5)) #Plotting code
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, hspace=0.1)
plt.subplot(231)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title("Original image")
plt.axis('off')
for idx, n_clusters in enumerate(n_colors):
   plt.subplot(232 + idx)
   plt.imshow(segmented_imgs[idx])
   plt.title("{} colors".format(n_clusters))
   plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

In this line of code,

```
segmented_img = kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_]
```

As the names suggest, cluster_centers_ is an array attribute that returns the coordinates of the cluster centers and labels_ is an attribute that returns the Labels of each point.
Hence segmented_img contains the cluster centre coordinates of the labels of each point. points.